# Firebase get vaule of serial number

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get the value of this automatically without writing each one separately.

[image]

I tried this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orutmen").child("episodeNumber");
```

but it shows null value.

This one works, but I have to write for each field:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orutmen").child("1").child("episodeNumber");
```

Here is the code

```java
m2Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orutmen");

m2Database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = snapshot.child("episodeNumber").getValue(String.class);
        Toast.makeText(EpisodeListModel.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate throught the `children` of `DataSnapshot`:

```java
m2Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Orutmen");

 m2Database.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value;
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            value = snapshot.child("episodeNumber").getValue(String.class);
            Toast.makeText(EpisodeListModel.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I did this before but it shows all values together so I want it to show only single value on item click

Comment: Right now since you're loading `Orutmen`, you're loading multiple nodes. Which value do you want to show?

Comment: I have a recyclerview so I want to assign each id (1,2,3) with the items so when I click the item it will show the episode number

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way

Just added a list of strings that collects the values from the snapshot
then retrieve the value by position of item clicked >>

```
     List<String> List = new ArrayList<>();

                                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String  value = snapshot.getKey();
                                    List.add(value);

                                }
Toast.makeText(EpisodeListModel.this, List.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```